# Material-UI - TypeScript - Autocomplete with getOptionLabel and renderOption

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to display `member` and `company` using  MUI `Autocomplete`.

I have `suggestion` array to show as `options`

```
[
    {
        "__typename": "Member",
        "id": "ckwa91sfy0sd241b4l8rekas9jx",
        "name": "my name 2",
        "companyName": ""
    },
    {
        "__typename": "Member",
        "id": "ckwac4ijl25dsd80b4l8fpsrc64o",
        "name": "my name",
        "companyName": ""
    },
    {
        "__typename": "Member",
        "id": "ckwa8z6z7004dsd2b4l81m6ras9c",
        "name": "my name 1",
        "companyName": "A COMPANY"
    }
]
```

I use this to display

```
 <Autocomplete
                                        id="free-solo-demo"
                                        freeSolo
                                        options={
                                            suggestion &&
                                            suggestion.map(
                                                (suggestion: any) =>
                                                    suggestion.name
                                            )
                                        }
                                        onChange={(event, value) =>
                                            HandleUserProfile(value)
                                        }
                                        renderInput={(params) => (
                                            <TextField
                                                {...params}
                                                placeholder="Search..."
                                                onChange={handleChange}
                                            />
                                        )}
                                    />
```

By using this I am getting options if only I search with `member` name.

I want to search with both `company` and `member` and need to customize UI of  option.

I tried this

```
 <Autocomplete
                                        id="free-solo-demo"
                                        freeSolo
                                        options={suggestion}
                                        getOptionLabel={(option) => `${option.name}  ${option.companyName}`}
                                        renderOption={(option)=>{
                                            return <h1>{`${option.name}: ${option.companyName}`}</h1>
                                        }}
                                        onChange={(event, value) =>
                                            HandleUserProfile(value)
                                        }
                                        renderInput={(params) => (
                                            <TextField
                                                {...params}
                                                placeholder="Search..."
                                                onChange={handleChange}
                                            />
                                        )}
                                    />
```

but It is not working.
it shows error `TypeScript error in ... Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'.  TS2339`

Answer (score -1):

First, you should make sure the `name` field doesn't have any duplicated values, that's why you should use the mandatory `id` field to select one.

And also you need to build a custom filter function or use `createFilterOptions` hook from `Autocomplete` component.

https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#custom-filter

```
import Autocomplete, { createFilterOptions } from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';

...
  const filterOptions = createFilterOptions({
    stringify: ({ name, companyName }) => `${name} ${companyName}`
  });

  <Autocomplete
    options={suggestion}
    getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
    filterOptions={filterOptions}
    ...
  />;
```