# Can not select MUI Autocomplete options

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to use `<Autocomplete/>` for searching members with **member name** or their **company name** like there are two members.

```
Name: "user 1"
company: ""
id:1
```

```
Name: "user 2"
company:"company 1"
id:2
```

now if I search `user 2` user 2 should come.
if I search `company 1` user 2 should come.

**Here is codesandbox.io for this**
https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-bassi-tqm7e?file=/src/App.tsx:766-1850

I have this working but the problem I am facing is while customizing `options` UI.

I want to display  `company` in smaller font and grey color and member name in regular font.

And I have a styled option, but now I can't select that options.

Here is my code.

```js
<Autocomplete
    id="free-solo-demo"
    freeSolo
    options={suggestion}
    onSelectCapture={(e) => { console.log(e) }}
    getOptionLabel={(option: any) =>
        `${option.name} ${option.companyName}`
    }
    selectOnFocus={true}
    renderOption={(option: any) => {
        console.log("option");
        console.log(option);
        return <h4>{`${option.key}`}</h4>;
    }}

    onChange={(event, value) => HandleUserProfile(value)}
    renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
            {...params}
            placeholder="Search..."
            onChange={handleChange}
        />
    )}
/>
```

Comment: Hello. Did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70120149/material-ui-typescript-autocomplete-with-getoptionlabel-and-renderoption/70126587#70126587) work for you?

Comment: @Samira, did you ever figure it out? I have the same problem. I can't select an option if I use `renderOption` which returns a simple <Box> component.